# Wildfly Standalone servers in cluster mode with same bind address -b 0.0.0.0 throwing address already in use exception

Tags: jboss, wildfly

We are using the link http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1952 to create two standalone servers in cluster mode.We are starting the servers as follows

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.bind.address.management=10.91.154.68 -Djboss.management.http.port=55011 -Djboss.server.config.dir=$fwkInstancesDir/server1/configuration  -Djboss.node.name=server1 -Djboss.ajp.port=8010 -Djboss.server.base.dir=$fwkInstancesDir/server1 -Djboss.http.port=55000


./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.bind.address.management=10.91.154.68 -Djboss.management.http.port=55031 -Djboss.server.config.dir=$fwkInstancesDir/server2/configuration  -Djboss.node.name=server2 -Djboss.ajp.port=8020 -Djboss.server.base.dir=$fwkInstancesDir/server2 -Djboss.http.port=55020
```

We are keeping the Bind address same for both the standalone servers. Both the servers get started and running, but the second server log shows error as below. When we try to connect to server through jboss-cli and get the JNDI view the second server is not shown. Is anyone having any suggestions regarding this issue?

```
[31m02:49:32,371 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.web.global-component-registry: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.web.global-component-registry: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type ChannelTransport
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:91) [wildfly-clustering-common-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type ChannelTransport
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:241)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.GlobalComponentRegistryService.start(GlobalComponentRegistryService.java:33)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:86) [wildfly-clustering-common-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type ChannelTransport
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:185)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530)
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:219)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:198)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:183)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: connecting to channel "web" failed
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._connect(JChannel.java:544)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:290)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:275)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:196)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to start server socket
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.down(FD_SOCK.java:321)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL.down(FD_ALL.java:218)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.down(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:84)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.down(NAKACK2.java:533)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.down(UNICAST3.java:576)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.down(STABLE.java:347)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.down(GMS.java:1045)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:340)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:340)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.down(FRAG2.java:136)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.RSVP.down(RSVP.java:142)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.down(ProtocolStack.java:1024)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.down(JChannel.java:760)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._connect(JChannel.java:538)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: bind_addr /0.0.0.0 is not a valid interface: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at org.jgroups.util.Util.createServerSocket(Util.java:3567)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.startServerSocket(FD_SOCK.java:584)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.down(FD_SOCK.java:318)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use two Wildfly instances with HA configuration on the same host, you have not only to check that HTTP, AJP etc use different ports, but also the JGroups-related ports.

Unlike the tutorial you are using, you don't seem to use `-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset`. Maybe you could try with that

Comment: Iam specifying the values of ports separately instead of giving offset. That will ensure that the ports are different for different standalone instances.

Answer (score 0):

JGroups cannot bind to 0.0.0.0, bind it to 127.0.0.1 or another IP instead.

Also, as mentioned using -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset is generally a good idea because you may miss a port for a service you aren't even thinking about.

Comment: We are now binding the JGroups to IP address and it is working fine. Thanks all.